# parse using dateutil

Tags: python

I have a csv file with data looking like (see below). I need help parsing datetime and fill missing date_time and assigning missing data as "M"(missing):

```
Datetime, Data

19920101 00:00,2
19920101 01:00,3
19920101 23:00,5
19920505 12:00,5
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also, what qualifies as a "missing date time" and "missing data" in this context?

Comment: To clarify: As you see my records the datetime jumps 22 hours from 19920101 01:00 to 19920101 23:00, I want to insert those missing hours and assign 'M' as data. I am a newbie in python and I am trying dateutil  with no success yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer but just tried to parse the date time string

```
>>> s="19920101 00:00"
>>> format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M"
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, format)
>>> print d
1992-01-01 00:00:00
```

Will this help in finding out the missing dates and times for you.

I could not understand what 3 is in the string `3 19920101 23:00`.

[Edit: based on your comment]

```
>>> expected = d + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> print expected
1992-01-02 00:00:00
```

So in your code, you could try something like this (You will need to work and refine this)

[Edit: Code replaced]

```
import csv
import sys
import datetime
import pprint


all_data_points = {}
all_dates = []
expected = ''
format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M"

with open('datafile', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row and 'Datetime' not in row:
            day_str = row[0]
            rain_str = row[1]
            if not expected:
                all_data_points[day_str] = rain_str
                all_dates.append(day_str)
                d = datetime.datetime.strptime(day_str, format)
                expected = d + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            else:
                d = datetime.datetime.strptime(day_str, format)
                gap_in_days = d - expected 
                start_day = expected
                if gap_in_days.days > 1:
                    for i in xrange(gap_in_days.days):
                        next_day = start_day + datetime.timedelta(days=1+i)
                        day_str = next_day.strftime(format)
                        all_data_points[day_str] = 'M'
                        all_dates.append(day_str)
                all_data_points[day_str] = rain_str
                expected = d

    pprint.pprint(all_data_points)
```

Comment: 3 is the rainfall data at that hour, i want to list datetime from 19920101 00:00 to 19931231 23:00 and if a datetime does not have a record, just assign a letter 'M'

Comment: Exactly that is what I should do, let me try , I am newbie in programming so that is why I was stack

Comment: I used your code, but where you wrote: all_data[day_str] , I get an error. I was thinking a list index cannot have the format that day_str has. am I right?

Comment: @EricGentil: I had corrected the typo. It should have been rain_str instead of rain[str]

Comment: so for all_data[day_str] in your code assumes 19920101 00:00 it is a range for the list, does python ignore the space between 1 and 00..and takes it as in integer??

Comment: This code considers the time step as a day while as you can see my dataset have a hour time step.

Comment: @Eric Gentil: Sorry. I saw the time gap from 19920505 to 19920101 as 125 days and thought the step may be in days. You can always use datetime.timedelta(hours=1+i) and also compare hours rather than days in the solution. Every thing else should work as per the above logic. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot...it now works, i changed a little bit..since timedelta does not have hours as attribute i transformed the time gap into hours using timedelta.total_seconds()/3600.